# in Sqlalchemy can I add a column with "source table" name in union?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have these two tables - sales and purchases. And then "stock" which is related to them. This is Flask-Sqlalchemy by the way, but I don't know if that's important.

```
class Sales(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "sales"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    stock_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'stocks.id'), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=1)
    unit_price = db.Column(db.Numeric, nullable=False)
    total_price = db.Column(db.Numeric, nullable=False)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                     default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())


class Purchases(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "purchases"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    stock_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'stocks.id'), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=1)
    unit_price = db.Column(db.Numeric, nullable=False)
    total_price = db.Column(db.Numeric, nullable=False)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                     default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

class Stock(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "stocks"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    symbol = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

I need to make an overview of the complete transactions (and then join it with the Stock table to be able to see the name of the product being sold/bought)

These two tables are identical. The only difference is that one is sales and one is purchases. And I need to make this clear in the data resulting from the query - which rows are from "sales" and which are from "purchases"

1. Would it have been smarter to make one table instead with all transactions and a column for specifying whether it was a sale or a purchase from the beginning? Or using positive and negative numbers for "price total"?
2. Can I make a union of the two tables but somehow also specify what rows came from what table? Like adding an extra column where the content is "0" if it's a sale and "1" if it's a purchase?
3. If someone would show me some example queries including how to also make the join to include "stock symbol" or "stock name" coming from the Stock table I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your three questions:

1. I guess you can always doubt your db scheme. There are always advantages and disadvantages to any solution of which there usually are plenty. So imho your solution is as good as the next one.
2. and 3. Based on the solution from @PGHE

```py
from sqlalchemy import union, join
from sqlalchemy.sql import literal_column

q1 = db.session.query(
        literal_column("'Purchases'").label("SourceTable"), #beware of the double quotes!
        Purchases.stock_id.label("PurchaseStockId"),
        Stock.id.label("StockId")
    ).join(
        Purchases,
        Purchases.stock_id == Stock.id
    )

q2 = db.session.query(
        literal_column("'Sales'").label("SourceTable"), # double quotes again
        Sales.stock_id.label("SalesStockId"),
        Stock.id.label("StockId")
    ).join(
        Sales,
        Sales.stock_id == Stock.id
    )

q3 = q1.union(q2).all()
```

I did not check the code on this specific example but just used the exact same construct in another situation. You might also want to consider using sqlalchemy 2.0 style querying (provided the issue is still of importance to you...).

Comment: Thanks for the catch. You could even wrap the `text` clause in `column_literal` so you don't need to beware of the double quotes. I'll remove my answer.